# Passing a value to the constructor of a CoffeeScript class

Tags: coffeescript

I'm trying to pass a value to the constructor of a CoffeeScript Class without success:

```
class A

  constructor: () ->

    @b = new B('FOO')
```

```
class B

  constructor: (@value) ->

  printValue: () =>
    console.log @value
```

When I call printValue from an instance of B then 'undefined' is logged in the console. Why is 'FOO' not being logged?

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned Class A instance is created in a third class C, like so:

```
class C

  constructor: () ->

    @a = new A()
```

All three classes are in different files and joined together in this order C ontop of A on top of C.

Comment: Works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/XNaAe/

Comment: Can you please add the line where you invoke `printValue()`?

Comment: the print value is called from a click handler  
$('body').on 'click', '#add_bts', ->

Comment: Ok, but what would be really interesting is the line that actually contains "printValue()". Could you post that as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do this, it works just fine:

```
class B
  constructor: (@value) ->
  printValue: () -> alert @value

b = new B "foo"
b.printValue()
```

I am guessing that you have a whitespace indenting issue happening.  Since CoffeeScript is whitespace sensitive, your tabs/spacing needs to be consistent within the same block.

Go over to to http://coffeescript.org/ and select "Try Coffeescript".  Paste it in and press "run".

OR, consider creating a JSFiddle that shows this issue, because I don't see a problem.